# How do I see a content of a specific cell in a tibble?

Tags: r, tibble

I tried `df["row_name", 2]` to get a cell which is located at row "row_name" and the second column, but there's an error

> Error: Can't subset with `[` using an object of class function.

Comment: You need to specify a rowname that exists. I doubt that there is any rowname the is "rowname".

Comment: You should also be aware that one of the main points of tibbles is that they strip rownames a lot of the time, in accordance with the opinionated take of the tidyverse. Subsetting with `[` removes rownames, and so does `as_tibble` by default, see the [documentation here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tibble/versions/1.4.2/topics/rownames).

Comment: Normally the error is a little different, but are you sure that your data is named `df`, and you aren't working with the *function* [`df`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.2/topics/FDist)? (Typically the error in that case is *"object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"*, but the mention of "class function" got me thinking.)

Answer (score 1):

When using a tibble, ‘[‘ returns another tibble. To subset, try ‘[[‘ or ‘$’ :

```
df2 <- tibble(x = 1:3, y = 3:1)
class(df2$x)
#> [1] "integer"
```

For example:

```
my.tibble<-tibble(x=c('Jack','Jill','Bill'),
              y=c('Fell','Stood','Slipped')
              )
> my.tibble
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  x     y      
  <chr> <chr>  
1 Jack  Fell   
2 Jill  Stood  
3 Bill  Slipped
```

```
> my.tibble[2,2]
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  y    
  <chr>
1 Stood
```

Likewise...

```
> my.tibble$x[2]
[1] "Jill"
```

or

```
my.df<-tibble('row_name' = c('Row A','Row B','Row C'),
              'other_rows' = c('Row 1A', 'Row1B', 'Row1C'))

> my.df$row_name[2]
[1] "Row B"
```

See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/tibble.html

=============Updated [based on request clarification===========

From the documentation [here] (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tibble/versions/1.4.2/topics/rownames), 'are removed when subsetting with the `[` operator'.

However, let us see if this gets you where you want.

Create dummy data from `iris` data:

```
> df_1<-iris[1:10,]
```

Add row.names:

```
> row.names(df_1)<-c('Obs1','Obs2','Obs3','Obs4','Obs5','Obs6','Obs7','Obs8','Obs9','Obs10')
```

Transform to tibble:

```
library(tibble) 
> df_1 <- as_tibble(rownames_to_column(df_1))

> head(df_1)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  rowname Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
  <chr>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
1 Obs1             5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
2 Obs2             4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
3 Obs3             4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
4 Obs4             4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
5 Obs5             5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
6 Obs6             5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa
```

Use `dplyr` to filter:

library(dplyr)

```
> filter(df_1,rowname=="Obs1" & Petal.Length == 1.4)
# A tibble: 1 x 6
  rowname Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
  <chr>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
1 Obs1             5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa
```

Another option. You can combine `filter` and `select`. In this example, I am telling R to first filter by row name 'Obs1' and then select the column 'Petal.Length' which returns the single value (1.4)

```
> filter(df_1,rowname=="Obs1") %>%
+   select(Petal.Length)
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  Petal.Length
         <dbl>
1          1.4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but seems I didn't write what I want well. In your last example, I want to get value "Row1B" by the command, that contains not a number, but a string of "row_name", something like `get_the_value[df, "row_name" = "Row B"]` and it must output "Row1B"

Comment: Is the intent to locate a specific value by calling RowName and ColName instead of index? Bases on your example, if you used a query like ‘[df,”row_name”=“Row B] (*this is not a logical command in R) it would return the entire row. However,I believe you want just one value.. I think we can get there with dplyr! Ill post a edit for you to try out :-) in a bit.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov updated, let me know if this is what you were looking to accomplish.